# Adding back slash for quotes in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the following code in Objective-C:

```
NSString *someString = @"Hello World";
```

I need a Swift Code with the following output: `\"Hello World\"`

Including the double checkmarks and the backslash.

Comment: doesnt make much sense your question brah

Comment: I just want to add "slash" right before the quotes.

Comment: do you mean that you want the string (\"Hello World\")? (Brackets used in place of quotes to make reading it easier)

Comment: see my latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you'll need this:

```
var mySuperFancyDynamicString: String = "whaaaazzuppp"

let someString: String = "\\\"\(mySuperFancyDynamicString)\\\""
print(someString)
```

print is `\"whaaaazzuppp\"` (well... was Hello World, before the edit)

[image]

Or to your "text box" Comment:

```
var mySuperFancyDynamicString: String = textBox.text
let someString: String = "\\\"\(mySuperFancyDynamicString)\\\""
print(someString)
```

Print will be : `\"textBoxContent\"`

Comment: The code is sent as a string so something like this: NSString *code = "NSString *str = \" Hello World \" "

Comment: i see. gimme a sec

Comment: I forgot to add that the text is all dynamic and coming from a text box. The user will only add code and not slashes. The question is how to parse the string and put those slashes in there.

Comment: no problem. sec. please stay. i'll have that added in 30 secs

Comment: Thanks! The someString can have multiple lines of code. Thats okay. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to convert from Objective-c to swift, if yes then don't add backslash to your double quotes, String in swift are just double quoted text.

You should end with

```
someString = "Hello World"
```

If You don't want to convert to swift then what are you doing ? Cause the code you are providing (`NSString *someString = @\"Hello World\";`) will throw an error.

EDIT :

If you really need that specific output, you must create a string like that :

```
someString = "\\\"Hello World\\\""
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to send it to the service which expects that parameter. If I don't add a back slash to the quotes then the service does not work. It is a third party service.